# How do I document useState hooks with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to use JSDoc to document the destructured parts of my react state hooks for example:

```js
const [referenceState, setReferenceState] = useState(null);
```

Here, `referenceState` is of type Object, and `setReferenceState` expects an Object.

Based on some information online, I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```js
/**
* @param {Object} stateToSet
* @returns {GenericArray} current state and function to change value
*/
const [referenceState, setReferenceState] = useState(null);
```

But that doesn't generate anything..

Can someone please help me document `referenceState` and `setReferenceState`?

Comment: What type is `referenceState`? An object? and what params does `setReferenceState` expect and return?

Comment: @BrettZamir sorry I didn't add those details. I've edited the question. And you're right, `referenceState` is an object, while `setReferenceState` expects an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try this approach:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ReferenceState
 */

/**
 * @callback ReferenceStateSetter
 * @param {ReferenceState} state
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * @namespace {Object}
 * @property {ReferenceState} 0
 * @property {ReferenceStateSetter} 1 
 */
const [referenceState, setReferenceState] = useState(null);
```

Or, to avoid having to document the immediately destructured array, but benefiting from adding some indent changes at the end:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ReferenceState
 */

/**
 * @callback ReferenceStateSetter
 * @param {ReferenceState} state
 * @returns {void}
 */

const [
    /**
     * @type {ReferenceState}
     */
    referenceState,

    /**
     * @type {ReferenceStateSetter}
     */
    setReferenceState
] = useState(null);
```

If you don't want to have documents for `ReferenceState`, you can get rid of its `@typedef` and replace references to it with `Object`, but I think it is clearer to have docs.

`void` above is a simpler way to say nothing special (i.e., `undefined`) is returned--if that's what the setter returns. Some projects would just drop the `@returns` if it only returns `undefined`, but I like to add it to show the return value is known to be `undefined` and not merely undocumented.

Answer (score 9):

In webstorm, You can write like this (I haven't tested it in other editors):

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(/** @type {{name: string, age: number?}} */null)
```

or

```js
/**
 * @typedef People
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {number} [age]
 */

//........

const [state, setState] = useState(/** @type {People} */null)
```

Comment: This is working also in vscode

Comment: In VS Code you will need parentheses around `null`.
`const [state, setState] = useState(/** @type {People} */(null))`

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE:
Seems the most readable short solution is to use ReturnType

```
/**
 * @type {ReturnType<typeof useState<number>>}
 */
const [num, setNum] = useState(null);
```

The shortest way is this: by adding a template

```
/**
 * @type {[MyType, React.Dispatch<MyType>]} state
 */
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

I also use *.d.ts files in the js projects. VS code sees them and uses them so you can describe types and interfaces in a modern way.

Just put a line

```
type useState<T> = [T, React.Dispatch<T>];
```

to a useState.d.ts file and then in a JS file use

```
/** @type {useState<MyType>} */
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

Comment: For some reason the typecast I wrote above works fine only with useState(null). If you provide some decent initial state value, then this value type overloads the casted type.. and even more interesting... in the useState line VS code still shows casted type, but below the value has type of the value inside useState.
The solution with providing type inside useState() is more robust. Despite it looks much worse I use it sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a generic type that equals the same return type as React's useState function.

```js
/**
 * Add this type in top of your file, or if commonly used in some types file.
 * @template T
 * @typedef {[T, import('react').Dispatch<import('react').SetStateAction<T>>]} useState
 */
```

Then you could use it in you React component like this:

```js
/** @type {useState<string>} */
const [someString, setSomeString] = useState('');

/** @type {useState<number>} */
const [someNumber, setSomeNumber] = useState(2);
```

Or if you want to use a custom object:

```
/**
 * @typedef SomeOtherType
 * @property {string} property1
 * @property {number} property2
 */

/** @type {useState<SomeOtherType>} */
const [someOtherValue, setSomeOtherValue] = useState(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, the variables can be declared prior to destructuring and annotated with JSDoc as normal.

```
/**
* Current state.
* @type {Object}
*/
let referenceState;
/**
* Current state setter.
* @type {Function}
* @param {any} state updated state value.
* @returns void
*/
let setReferenceState;
[referenceState, setReferenceState] = useState(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the initial value in `useState(value)` a type.

The TypeScript types included with `@types/react` will be used to infer the type of your destructured array values. If you are using Create React App (`react-scripts`) then you should already have `@types/react` installed. Otherwise it can be installed as a devDependency.

Note the brackets around `null`, which will help if using VSCode, which checks JSDoc types with TypeScript. See [How to cast TypeScript type in javascript using JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101584/how-to-cast-typescript-type-in-javascript-using-jsdoc).

*string example*

```js
const [name, setName] = useState(/** @type {string?} */ (null));
```

*object example*

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{ name: string, age: number}} Person
 */

const [people, setPeople] = useState(/** @type {Person[]?} */ (null));
```