# How to cast TypeScript type in javascript using JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

When using TypeScript to check JavaScript code, how do you cast to a different type than is inferred? Typescript has the `<Type>` and `as Type` syntax but these aren't valid in JavaScript.

```
/**
 * @param {{id: string, value: number}} details - object with required properties
 */
function stringifyObject(details) {
  return `${details.id}: ${details.value}`;
}

const testValue = {id: 'no-value'};
stringifyObject(testValue); // want to cast testValue to ignore missing property
stringifyObject(/** @type {any} */ testValue); // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `/** @type */` comment is close. According to the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts) it just needs parenthesis around the value being cast.

> TypeScript borrows cast syntax from Google Closure. This lets you cast types to other types by adding a `@type` tag **before any parenthesized expression**.

So in the original example you would write the following:

```
// Wrap value being cast in parenthesis 
stringifyObject(/** @type {any} */ (testValue));
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

*The Answer is already given in another post. 

But to add more on the usage:*

#### in short (repeated from details)

- if you want to let the type cast be available in all the code lines below, use this

  ```js
  node_curr = /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr);  // working for this line & all the lines below
  node_curr.outerHTML;
  ```

#### details

- vv

  ```js
      // #>>> an example usage
      const elt_main = $('<div></div>')[0];
      const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(elt_main, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);

      const arr_html_EltMain = [];
      let html_curr;
      let node_curr;
      while ((node_curr = treeWalker.nextNode())) {
        const nt = node_curr.nodeType;
        if (nt === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          html_curr = /** @type {Text} */ (node_curr).textContent;
          arr_html_EltMain.push(html_curr);
        } else if (nt === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          html_curr = /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr).outerHTML; // << the Type cast / autocompletion will only apply to this particular line, 
          //                                                          // any reference below this line will fall back to original Type
          //                                                          // also, if you hover to the variable, it appears to be still the old Type (though autocompletion works)
          arr_html_EltMain.push(html_curr);
        }
      }

      // #>>> 
      // @note: about the paranthesis -- only enclose it for the variable, not need to include the @type
      (/** @type {Element} */ (node_curr)).outerHTML;  // works, but unnecessary 
      /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr).outerHTML;    // use this

      // #>>> 
      // compare & the correct way to use 
      /** @type {Element} */ node_curr = node_curr;    // not_working                                        
      node_curr;                                       // not_working    
      (/** @type {Element} */ node_curr) = node_curr;  // not_working                                          
      node_curr;                                       // not_working    
      /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr) = node_curr;  // working only for this line
      node_curr;                                       // not_working    
      node_curr = /** @type {Element} */ node_curr;    // not_working                                       
      node_curr;                                       // not_working    
      node_curr = (/** @type {Element} */ node_curr);  // not_working                                         
      node_curr;                                       // not_working    
      node_curr = /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr);  // working for this line & all the lines below
      node_curr;                                       // working    
      node_curr;                                       // working    
      node_curr;                                       // working    

      // #>>> 
      // @note: if you want to let the type cast be available in all the code lines below, use this
      node_curr = /** @type {Element} */ (node_curr);  // working for this line & all the lines below
      node_curr.outerHTML;
  ```

#### other info (minor)

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25028

Comment: I don't see it on your list, but I also had success with `let /** @type {Element} */ node_curr;`. Probably not useful for the original example or when you otherwise need to narrow later in code, but I think still worth mentioning.